# 414 Errors from Nginx turn into 503 errors in Varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish

I have Nginx running behind Varnish currently. Occasionally users send very long spurious URIs, which translate into Nginx 414s. Unfortunately, when those 414s are given to Varnish, in turns them into 503s, which are then returned to the user. This is very frustrating, and I'd prefer returning a 414 instead as we monitor 503s and consider these unexpected. What can I do to have Varnish preserve the 414s from Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

the 503 response is correct in this case because, due to the 414s, Varnish was not able to connect the the backend(which in this case is Ngnix).
Varnish will return a 503 to the client because the connection didn't happen.
You can save those 414 response from nginx in a Varnish header and monitor those.

```
sub vcl_backend_error {
    if(beresp.status == 414) {
      'set the header here'
    }
}
```

The same logic can be applied in sub vcl_deliver.